# Unable to locate SystemManufacturers namespace

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm trying to add a reference to the [SystemManufacturers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.systemmanufacturers.aspx) namespace, but I can't seem to figure out why this is inaccessible to me.

The API docs say it is available for Windows 8, but this namespace is not included when creating a Windows Store app, and I'm also unable to reference it in a Windows class library.

I found the System.Windows.Profile.SystemManufacturers.dll in C:\Windows\System32, but Visual Studio will not let me add a reference to it saying "Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Has anyone ran into this, or similar scenario before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this namespace [require special permissions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a93fdff5-2443-4ab9-abc7-40d0e1e234da/runtime-error-running-metro-store-app-with-smbiosinformationserialnumber?forum=tailoringappsfordevices).

[This document describes it](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CFgQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile27.uf.tistory.com%2Fattach%2F2122EF4C523FDC050AE95D&ei=pWfgUo3DDsnP4QS_pIGwAw&usg=AFQjCNHMphRSjZ65RgBSAP7Zc7_NmiNYjQ&sig2=WCaBCVAA0kePqJBi9VT7RA&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bGE).

> Only applications that are declared as privileged in the device
>   metadata of the PC container have access to this API. The list or
>   privileged apps in the device metadata of the PC container is governed
>   by an OEM. For more information on how to declare a privileged
>   application in device metadata, refer to Privileged Applications
>   element and Specifying applications in the Device Metadata Authoring
>   Wizard under Privileged applications. The system serial number data
>   will be retrieved from the Serial Number field (offset 07h) in the
>   System Information (Type 1) structure as described in the System
>   Management BIOS (SMBIOS) Reference 6 Specification. OEMs should ensure
>   that the serial number is specified correctly in this field.

Comment: ah, I knew it had something to do with this, but I didn't realize it was governed by the OEM. Boo. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're trying to reference an unmanaged (also called native) DLL. The solution to this is to use [`DLLImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) like so for `user32.dll`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```

You can read more on the difference between normal DLLs and .NET DLLs [here](http://www.anotherchris.net/net/inside-net-assemblies-part-1/).